# how we can get original data in geo server using encryption in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, encryption, openlayers-3, geoserver

I am about to implement specific columns encryption in PostgreSQL

```
INSERT INTO friend (name, age) 
VALUES ( PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('abc'::character varying,current_setting('encrypt.key')),
PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('28'::character varying,current_setting('encrypt.key')));
```

but I have geometry data as well in my database which is published on GeoServer,
how do I retrieve original data in GeoServerwhich is there in my database in encryption format.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no support for encrypted columns in the [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) [PostGis module](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html). Therefore the only way to handle this would be to [write new code](https://geotools.org/getinvolved.html) to implement it.